# rails route match 'location' and 'Location'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

`match '/l|L/ocation' => redirect(...`

I'm hoping to do something like that. I can add a separate line for this redirect, but it seems silly.

Comment: `match "#{/location/i}"` would be awesome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use regexes directly in your routes. You could, however, use a [dynamic segment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) along with a constraint on that, which allows regexes just fine.

Something like this:

```
match '/:path', constraints: { path: /location/i }
```

Comment: mmmm... this isn't going to a controller though. that's essentially globbing. this is just a static url redirecting to facebook, or something.